# Negative Expectation of a constant is positive or negative

Tags: probability, inference

Say, I have a normal distribution $ X  \sim N(\mu, \sigma)$, where $\mu$ unknown and $\sigma^2$ known

Then, $-E[2/\sigma]=2/\sigma$ or $-2/\sigma$

This is in reference to the Fisher Information where you have $-E(\cdot)$ of something.

Edit:
I was taking expectation of Fisher Information.
$$-E[\frac{1}{2\sigma^4}-\frac{(X-\mu)^2}{\sigma^6}|\mu, \sigma^2]=\frac{1}{2\sigma^4}$$
where did the negative sign go?

Comment: I guess I don't understand the dilemma. $E(c) = c$ for any constant, $c$. Multiply through by $-1$ and you have $-E(c) = -c$. Were you asking anything else?

Comment: I just edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know $X-\mu$ has a $N(0,\sigma^2)$ distribution. So

$$E( (X-\mu)^2 ) = {\rm var}(X-\mu) + [E(X-\mu)]^2 = \sigma^{2} + 0 = \sigma^2$$

therefore

$$E\left(\frac{(X-\mu)^2}{\sigma^6}\right) = \frac{1}{\sigma^6} \cdot E( (X-\mu)^2 )  = \frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^{6}} = \frac{1}{\sigma^4}$$

which implies

$$-E \left [\frac{1}{2\sigma^4}-\frac{(X-\mu)^2}{\sigma^6}\right] = -\frac{1}{2\sigma^4} + \frac{1}{\sigma^4} = \frac{1}{2\sigma^4}$$

Comment: got it!  I kept on thinking you can push expectation through into the square in first equation, which is a mistake.

Comment: A common mistake. Most definitely $E(f(X)) \neq f(E(X))$ except in a few cases (e.g. $f$ is a linear function). See Jensen's Inequality for more info on that.

Answer (score 1):

If $\sigma$ is the standard deviation then it is positive (or at least non-negative).

If $\sigma$ is a constant then $$-E\left[ \frac 2 \sigma \right] = -\frac 2 \sigma$$

In the expression for the [Fisher Information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information) you can often find

$$
\mathcal{I}(\theta) = - \operatorname{E} \left[\left. \frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta^2} \log f(X;\theta)\right|\theta \right]\,
$$

the sign is present because the expectation is negative.  There is another expression $$\mathcal{I}(\theta)=\operatorname{E} \left[\left. \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta} \log f(X;\theta)\right)^2\right|\theta \right]$$ withought the negative sign.

Comment: wow, thanks Henry, you wrote exactly what I was having trouble with.

Comment: The problem had -E[what you had]=-E[1/(2*sigam^4)-((x-mu)^2)/sigma^6]=1/(2*sigma^4). Where did the negative sign go in the end?

Comment: Wiki is saying -E[] or E[] depending on the situation as long as the expectation don't come out negative?